# Creating and utilizing MySQL Indexes

Tags: mysql, asp.net, indexing

I'm reading about MySQL Indexes and still have a few questions.

First off I have a ASP.NET application with MySQL InnoDB database.  I have a table named `userstable` with the following columns: `last_name`, `middle_name`, `first_name`, `email`.

If I wanted to create an index based off the last name I could create the index as such:

```
CREATE INDEX last_name_index ON userstable (last_name);
```

Now I have this following query to select data, and my question is if this regular SQL query has to be modified to utilize the index?  If so, how?

```
SELECT * FROM userstable WHERE last_name="johnson"
```

Also I've read that if you're adding rows to your table that the indexes have to be updated because the indexes can become out of date.

Does that mean I should arbitrarily issue this command `CREATE INDEX last_name_index ON userstable (last_name);` every so many entries into the table?

Answer (score 1):

SQL engines use indexes automatically.  In general, the optimizer determines whether an index is appropriate and which index to use for a query (more than one might be applicable).

Your query would typically use an index.  The one exception might be if the table had just a handful of rows.  Then scanning the table could be faster than an index lookup.

As for keeping indexes up-to-date, that is also done automatically.  You don't really have to worry about it.  If you do lots of deletes and updates, your index (and table) could end up less efficient than if created from scratch.  This phenomenon is called *index fragmentation* (and is documented [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/innodb-file-defragmenting.html)).  So, under some circumstances, for maintaining the database and keeping it clean, you do want to rebuild the indexes.  However, this is rather rare and not usually necessary on tables where you are just inserting new values.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.  In your second paragraph you said that my query would typically use an index, does that mean that my simple SELECT * FROM userstable WHERE last_name="johnson" query already uses the index? i.e. I don't have to explicitly change that query at all to have the database use the index?

Comment: @CDuran . . . No changes at all.  You can look at the explain plan to see if it does.  (Just put explain before the query and you get the execution steps.)